# Run a server with a GUI

Tags: server, gui

I'm sorry but I'm an absolute beginner and have difficulty typing.

I have an HP Proliant DL36 and friend has installed a GUI on it for me. 
For the time-being I will run it with direct console access (Mouse and keyboard interface), only connecting to the internet to download what I need to install.

Once it's up and running I'll have to access it through a web portal.

On to my question: *Does anyone know of a tutorial, to set up a server and services using an Ubuntu GUI interface?*

To clarify, I want to replicate a Windows Server look-and-feel to see what services have stopped, or what problems there are. I'm looking to replicate that as near as possible with Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI interface to configure, monitor and control the server and services running?

Answer (score 0):

You need VNC for this, over SSH. So you need to install openssh-server and vnc-server. You don't tell us what version of Ubuntu it is, so I guess 14.04 LTS, so google if you have another version.

- [Install Open SSH server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)
- [How To Install VNC Server On Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows which has different kernels for the server and the workstation, **Ubuntu has only one kernel**...  :-)

So you shouldn't be trying to install a bare-bones server and then add a GUI, but just install the desktop version *and then add all the server components you need*. (Mysql, vsftpd, Apache, ...)

Then install SSH and VNC as mentioned by [SPBRN](https://askubuntu.com/users/55365/sprbrn)

A few extra's that will give you GUI server management:

- [BUM - Boot-Up Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-up-manager-bum-graphical-runlevel-editor.html)
- MySQL WorkBench (for SQL servers)
- Apache GUI
- ...

You *could* use a "Web hosting control panel" (google it) like [Ajenti](http://ajenti.org/) but I would strongly advise against it as you will not have any deep knowledge of your server and in Linux (as in Windows), you *need* the CLI to do anything remotely advanced.

Oh? You think advanced stuff doesn't need a CLI on Windows??? Try doing a `fsutil behavior set memoryusage 2` on a Windows server using a GUI! >:)